# Difference between 2 mono/stereo setup?

Tags: live-sound, setup

Don't mind about "Guitar", it could be Bass or anything else. Imagine you have 2 setups:

1. `Guitar -> Pedals (stereo end) -> 2 Amps running -> Mixer`
2. `Guitar -> Pedals (mono end) -> 1 Amp running -> Rec Out/Phones -> Split to 2 channel -> Mixer`

Let's say (on 1st option) rather than running the delay in stereo, I run it on mono (so it won't have ping-pong delay), but I put chorus and reverb in stereo. On the other option, I pan each channel (on the mixer) hard left and hard right. Would it be any difference? If there is, what's the differences?

Comment: You've already alluded to the difference, in your question - If the chorus and reverb are stereo algorithms, then you'll lose their stereo effect by going to mono then splitting.

Answer (score 4):

Once you've lost the stereo image by going mono, the signal in any split subsequently will be the same in both channels. So each side will sound the same. If there is a stereo output,initially, from whatever pedal, then that integrity needs to be retained, as the moment it gets 'monoised', there will be no difference between each sound, left/right or one/two channel.